# how to send messageid through form post without using name and value php

Tags: php, forms, post

So I have this site where user can have profiles and send guestbook messages. If youre logged in and viewing your messages each message have a submit button to delete that message.

I know how to delete this message and all but i cant figure out how to get the messageID when posting.

a controller makes a loop with all messages with this (one message):

```
{   $this->theMessageID = $messageID;

    $guestbookHtml .= "<div id='guestbook'>
                    <form method='post' action='' class='deletemsg'>
                    <input class='deleteinput' type='submit' name='$this->m_delete' value='delete'/>
                    </form>                     
                    <p class='message'>$message</p>
                    </div>"; 


    return $guestbookHtml;
}
```

and then I have this function that checks if ive pressed one button

```
 {
    if (isset($_POST[$this->m_delete])) {
         return true;
    } else {
         return false;
    }
 }
```

and yeah now how do I send $this->theMessageID to my controller also depending on which of the messages ive pressed.... :)

Comment: What is your concrete question? What is your concrete programming problem?

Comment: You could store the messageid inside a session variable and then access that value on another page, i.e., the page where the form variables are posting to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a hidden field and store the id you want to delete.

```
{   $this->theMessageID = $messageID;

    $guestbookHtml .= "<div id='guestbook'>
                    <form method='post' action='' class='deletemsg'>
                    <input type='hidden' name='{$this->m_delete}' value='{$this->theMessageID}'/>
                    <input class='deleteinput' type='submit' value='delete'/>
                    </form>                     
                    <p class='message'>$message</p>
                    </div>"; 


    return $guestbookHtml;
}
```

So, if `$_POST[$this->m_delete]` is set, then the deleted ID is in `$_POST[$this->m_delete]`